# I failed to evaluate double integral

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I try to evaluate this symbolic integral and evaluate its two series expansions according to certain variables, the plot the output providing some numerical values.

This is a relativistic rotational hollow disk. This one my thought experiments I try to figure it out. I am a hobbyist physicist

---

```
f1 = (y (-z + 
       y Cos[x]))/(((1 - (\[Omega] y)^2/h^2)^(1/2)) ((z^2 + y^2 - 
         2 z y Cos[x])^(3/2)));
f2 = Assuming[0 < z < 0.99 ymin  && 0.99 h > \[Omega] y, 
   Integrate[f1, {y, ymin, ymax}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}] // FullSimplify];
S2 = Assuming[0 < z < 0.99 ymin  && 0.99 h > \[Omega] y, 
  Series[f2, {z, 0, 3}, {\[Omega], 0, 4}] // FullSimplify]
S3 = Assuming[0 < z < 0.99 ymin  && 0.99 h > \[Omega] y, 
  Series[f2, {w, 0, 3}] // FullSimplify]
\[Omega] = 1;
w = z \[Omega]^2;
h = 1000;
ymin = 500;
ymax = 985;
Plot[f2, {w, 0, 495}]
```

---

My Question is: I takes very very long time, and I lost the hope to see result. I use the trial version of the most recent Mathematica.

Is there something wrong in this code?

------------ at Aug 28 2020 --------------

What if I try to fix z and plot versus omega provided that ymin>z>ymax. There will be divergence at z, so I tried to divide the integral to two integrals and take the limit at z to solve the improper integrations, the one that has ymin1>z>ymax1, and the other that has ymin2>z>ymax2. It didn't give me any result. Here is a trial to fix z and do series and plot with respect to omega.

```
f1[z_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, ymin1_?NumericQ, 
   ymax1_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(y (-z + 
        y Cos[x]))/(((1 - (\[Omega] y)^2/h^2)^(1/2)) ((z^2 + y^2 - 
          2 z y Cos[x])^(3/2))), {y, ymin1, ymax1}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
f2[z_?NumericQ, \[Omega]_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, ymin2_?NumericQ, 
   ymax2_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[(y (-z + 
        y Cos[x]))/(((1 - (\[Omega] y)^2/h^2)^(1/2)) ((z^2 + y^2 - 
          2 z y Cos[x])^(3/2))), {y, ymin2, ymax2}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, 
   Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];
f3 = f1 + f2;
L1 = Limit[f1[1, \[Omega], 1000, 0, ymx1], ymx1 -> 1, 
  Assumptions -> ymx1 < 1]
L2 = Limit[
  f2[1, \[Omega], 1000, ymn2, ymx2], {ymn2 -> 1, ymx2 -> 250}, 
  Assumptions -> ymn2 > 1 && ymx2 < 250  && \[Omega] < 4]
L3 = L1 + L2 

S1 = Series[L1, {\[Omega], 0, 4}]
S2 = Series[L2, {\[Omega], 0, 4}]
S3 = Series[(L1 + L2), {\[Omega], 0, 4}]

P1 = Plot[L1, {\[Omega], 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "L1"}]
P2 = Plot[L2, {\[Omega], 0, 4}, AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "L2"}]
P3 = Plot[(L1 + L2), {\[Omega], 0, 4}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"\[Omega]", "L3"}]
```

And what if I need to get series and plot w.r.t. z also?

Comment: Also your plot range makes no sense because `w = z \[Omega]^2` and `f2` will have a mixture of `y` and `z`. Plot needs a single independent variable.

Comment: Hi flinty,
1- what is Rubi`; role?
2- y should not be an independent variable after integration from ymin to ymax

Comment: Apologies - I was integrating wrt  x.

Comment: Rubi is a package for [rule-based-integration](https://rulebasedintegration.org/) which can sometimes solve integrals when Mathematica cannot. It appears that even Rubi cannot do it when integrating over both y and x. You should therefore look into numerically integrating it.

Comment: @flinty Is numerical integration same but NIntegrate instead of Integrate?

Comment: yes, sort of but there are lots of differences. Could you please explain this first though `Plot[f2, {w, 0, 495}]` and `w = z \[Omega]^2;` ? 'w' is not in the expression f2 and you can't plot with the variable `z \[Omega]^2`

Comment: I am convinced now with your claim that plotting with"w" as an independent variable is nonsense. I it is enough to plot with z is the only independent value

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you'll have to go for numerical integration as neither Mathematica nor *Rubi* could calculate a symbolic integral.

```
f2[z_?NumericQ, ω_?NumericQ, h_?NumericQ, ymin_?NumericQ, ymax_?NumericQ] := 
  NIntegrate[
    (y (-z + y Cos[x]))/(((1 - (ω y)^2/h^2)^(1/2)) ((z^2 + y^2 - 2 z y Cos[x])^(3/2)))
  , {y, ymin, ymax}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]


Plot[f2[z, 1.0, 1000.0, 500.0, 985.0], {z, 0, 495}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"z", "f2"}]
```

[image: integral plot]

Comment: Great flinty, How much time it took from you to graph? And which version of Mathematica?

Comment: @AhmedKamalKassem with `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"` it's much faster, around 10s, but without that it takes a long time > 1min. I'm using Windows 10 Mathematica v12.1.1.0  home.

Comment: I tried the double integral, bot this time from 0 to ymax, so there is a divergence at y=z, if ymax>z>ymin, so, to avoid divergence for the improper integration I took the limit, but I don't get a result:
the new code:

Comment: @fliny
What if I try to fix z and plot versus omega, but z has the condition ymin>z>ymax. There will be divergence at z, so I tried to divide the integral to two integrals and take the limit at z to solve the improper integrations, the one that has ymin1>z>ymax1, and the other that has ymin2>z>ymax2. It didn't give me any result. I tried to put the code here in the comment it exceeded the number of letters allowed.